# Enabling digital input buffers on AVR ATmega1280 PORTF and PORTK

Tags: c++, c, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I'm trying to use `PORTF` and `PORTK` (the two attached to the ADC) of an ATmega1280 as digital inputs but `PINK` and `PINF` always contain `0x00` no matter what. This seems to be the expected behavior when configuring these ports only as analog inputs and disabling the digital input buffers, but I am actually doing the opposite, setting both `ADCSRx` registers to `0x00`, `ACSR` to `0x80` (Analog Comparator Disable, even if i don't think this should affect digital inputs) and each `DIDRx` to `0x00`.

Enabling internal pullups via `PORTx` doesn't affect the `PINx` registers

Is there anything else i am missing needed to enable them? I've searched a lot in the datasheet but i can't find anything else that could help

Here is a snippet of the current registers configuration, after which i continuously read `PINx` registers and print them to a serial. It is the only thing currently running on the MCU (other than the FreeRTOS scheduler)

```c
ADCSRA = 0x00;
ADCSRB = 0x00;

ACSR = 0b10000000;

DIDR0 = 0x00;
DIDR1 = 0x00;
DIDR2 = 0x00;

DDRK = 0x00;
DDRF = 0x00;
```

Comment: It does not require anything special to read `PINF` and `PINK`. Usually just enabling pull-ups (`DDRF = 0; DDRK = 0; PORTF = 0xFF; PORTK = 0xFF;`) should be enough, if inputs are left floated (not connected). Can you provide full code (how you're reading the registers and output their values) and also connection schematics?

Comment: That is what i was expecting and that is exactly what happens if i read those registers in a program without FreeRTOS, there must be something in the port that i'm using (feilipu/avrfreertos) that causes this behavior, i will check in its sources or open an issue in its gh. Electrically the ports are connected to optoisolators with a pullup resistor. This is my test code btw https://gist.github.com/vivedo/3958ade23352909804788786c31ee23d